# Method invocation in class definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => true
end
```

In the above, what is `validates` from a Ruby standpoint?  It's not a method *definition*, it's not a data definition or declaration. So, evidently it's a method *invocation*, right there in the body of the class.  I have never seen a method invoked like that directly in a class (i.e. outside of a method definition), not even in the Ruby programming tutorial I'm going through now: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/.

So, if it's a method invocation, at what point is it being invoked? I tried the following as a test:

```
class Person   

  print "cat"
    
end

#p = Person.new
#q = Person.new
```

`print "cat"` is being executed exactly once, regardless if any actual Person objects are being declared or not, so evidently just when parsing the class definition, Ruby sees the method print and says, "OK I will just go ahead and execute this now" but never does so again.

So, where is the Ruby documentation that will help me understand what is going on with `validates` above?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've read Programming Ruby, but I'm *pretty* sure message sends in class bodies are covered very early on, particularly `attr_reader`, `attr_writer` and `attr_accessor`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Ruby, class declarations are just chunks of code, executed in order.

It's important to remember that inside a class definition, `self` points to the class itself. `validates` is a class method of `ActiveRecord`. As the class is being defined, code in the definition is executed. The `validates` method resolves to a class method of `ActiveRecord`, so is called *during class definition*.

In your `Person` example, it will only print once, because you only define the class once.

Consider the following:

```
class Foo
  def self.validates_nothing(sym)
    (@@syms ||= []) << sym
    puts "!!! Here there be logic"
  end

  def validate
    @@syms.each { |s| puts s }
  end
end
```

This defines a class with a class method `validates_nothing`, and an instance method, `validate`. `validates_nothing` just gathers whatever arguments are given it, `validate` just dumps them out.

```
class Bar < Foo
  validates_nothing :anything
  validates_nothing :at_all
end
```

This defines a subclass. Note that when the class method `validates_nothing` is called, it prints:

```
Here there be logic
Here there be logic
```

If we create a new bar and call validate, we get the expected output:

```
> Bar.new.validate
!!!anything
!!!at_all
```

Comment: SO, how is "validates" getting executed in Rails.  "print cat" is not being called on new (where I would have assumed it would be called). Its just called once when the Ruby interpreter encounters "print cat" in the text for the first time and then never again apparently.

Comment: @Mark How? Because a class definition consists of Ruby code that's executed *as the class is being defined*. Calling `new` doesn't define the class, it creates a new instance. `validates` is called *during the class definition process itself*. You believe that the body of a class definition is executed during `new`, but that's incorrect, nor would it make sense--that would imply that method definitions, for example, would be re-executed (or defined, or something).

Comment: So, bear with me here, in the validates example above, validates is called exactly once, regardless of how many Person objects get declared?

Comment: Just for the record, my question wasn't where validates came from, I think I assumed it was defined in a parent class. Rather, it was how and when validates was executed.  I think you're confirming its executed exactly once, when its encountered in the class definition.

Comment: @Mark Yes; in your example, there is a single call to `validates`, called during *class definition*. That has nothing to do with instantiation, which is what happens when `new` is called.

Comment: @Mark I wasn't explaining "where it came from", I was explaining "it's a class method, in a class definition `self` is the class itself, thus `validates` resolves to a class method (which happens to be in `ActiveRecord`). Without understanding what `self` is in a class definition, or what method is being called, none of it will make much sense.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it.  (answered).