# Why is code inside of classes executed automatically when I run a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, class

When I write the following program,

```
class Classname
  puts "hi"
end
```

save it as a .rb file, and execute the file in terminal, the output "hi" is returned. I don't understand why. Don't I have to assign that puts statement to a method, create an object of the Classname class, and then call the method on said object to get that output? Or at least put the puts statement in the initialize method of the class, and then create an object? Why does this work the way it is?

Comment: when you use the `class` keyword to define a class, it actually constructs a new `Class` object and executes the internal code within its context. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9202363/591495

Comment: How would you define methods if the code inside the class didn't get executed? How would you call the `attr_accessor` method if the code inside the class didn't get executed? How would you create an instance if the class of the definition of the `initialize` didn't get executed before the object is initialized? Why would the definition of the `initialize` method have to be executed over and over and over again for every single instance you create?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby is a scripting language, which means that you can just write

```
puts 'hi'
```

in a file without defining any class or methods.

Similarly, when you are defining a class, you are actually executing code to define that class. As a result, code that you execute inside of it may have side effects, like `puts 'hi'`.  This is useful because metaprogramming is often used in Ruby to help define classes.